# Bug in Firebase Disk Persistence on Android? Can only push 30 new records

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

While testing the reliability of Disk Persistence on Android (Firebase SDK 2.2.2) I experienced a few limitations.

With airplane mode enabled and the app restarted (force closed) once after each new object added and value updated:

1. I can only push up to 30 new objects after that the oldest
   disappear.
2. I can only update an existing object 1-5 times (randomly varying).
   Then after an app restart the object value always resets to the last
   successfully updated value.

I experienced this with my own test app and also the Firebase AndroidChat example with `Firebase.getDefaultConfig().enablePersistence();` added to it's application class.

Are these general limitations of the Disk Persistence cache or might there be another problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to contact a Firebase developer which told me that the disk persistence should not have a limit on the cache size.

The issues I experienced are caused by a bug which will be fixed in the upcoming SDK version 2.2.3.

Comment: 2.2.3 has now been released. Thanks for following up here to help others, @sdeff!